# How to get count of each value against unique id in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have below mentioned table:

Where `Val` column has 3 distinct value a,b & c.

```
ID     Val
1      a
1      a
1      b
2      b
2      c
2      c
3      c
```

I want to get count of unique ids and count of ids for respective `Val` value (i.e a,b & c).

I am using query like this but it helps me to identify count for a single `Val` value at a time.

```
SELECT ID,COUNT(*) 
FROM table1
WHERE Val='c' GROUP BY ID;
```

Required output:

```
ID      count    a     b    c
1       3        2     1    0
2       3        0     1    2      
3       1        0     0    1
```

Comment: Does it need to be in this format?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by and sum the count when val is equal to a,b or c. See below:

```
select id, 
    count(*) as `count`, 
    sum(case when val = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as a, 
    sum(case when val = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as b, 
    sum(case when val = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) as c
from yourTable
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, count(*), sum(val = 'a') as a, sum(val = 'b') as b, sum(val = 'c') as c
from table1
group by id;
```

Comment: it give me error function sum(boolean) doesn't exist.

Comment: @VectorJX Tag your question with the correct RDBMS. This works for MySQL.

Comment: @VectorJX . . . Your question is tagged "mysql" and this is thoroughly valid MySQL code and the title of your question is:  "How to get count of each value against unique id in Mysql".